# C# Disc eject randomly fails saying the session has to close (not even burning a disc)

Tags: c#, file-copying, removable-storage

My users have been having an annoying issue lately.

I've got an app that basically takes images from a cd, dvd, or usb drive and copies them to the network.

When it's done copying it should automatically eject the disc.

The problem is, when a disc is done being copied and goes to eject, it takes a really long time.  One of my users said she waited an hour for it to finish closing and eject.

On other discs where this has happened, the user would try to hit the physical eject button and the bubble on windows 7 pops up and says please wait until the session is closed before ejecting.

Nothing is being burned to the disc and the disc is not a CD-RW or DVD-RW so I don't understand why it needs to close the session on the disc.

Is it possible that the person who originally burned the cd messed up somehow?

Out of 250+ discs that have gone through so far today, this only happened on two of them which leads me to believe something is wrong with these discs.

Here's my method that ejects the drive:

```
    private void Eject()
    {
        try
        {
            VolumeDeviceClass volumeDeviceClass = new VolumeDeviceClass();

            foreach (Volume device in volumeDeviceClass.Devices)
            {
                if (!device.IsUsb)
                    continue;

                if (device.LogicalDrive == null || (device.LogicalDrive.Length == 0))
                    continue;

                /* Should get down here if our device is a usb drive */
                device.Eject(true);
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            mciSendString("open " + _driveName.Substring(0, 2) + " type cdaudio alias cddrive", sb, 127, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciSendString("set cddrive door open", sb, 127, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Log(ex.Message, Logger.Severity.Error, "Error ejecting CD drive: " + Environment.MachineName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the eject sequence that is taking so long and not something like copying content to the network and a network slowdown occurs? To most users those things all look alike so unless you have logging or something else like a very clear message on the screen that indicates the exact position or method entry that is executing you might be looking in the wrong spot.

Comment: On the application it displays an icon once it's finished copying files to the network.  So I know it's done copying them over.

Comment: Good deal. So it could then either be a PC glitch or a disc glitch or maybe a combination. The best thing would be to see if you can duplicate it with a specific disc, can you ask the user(s) to set aside disc(s) that cause the problem? Then you can try to reproduce it locally while debugging the app and maybe get a little further. It's obviously not the code as you said it has worked without problem 250 out of 252 times.

Comment: Yeah I had them set a few a side and it's reproducible on multiple machines.  I've only tried windows 7 though.  I'll add more info soon.